# django can't serialize non-model on post

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

New to django and trying to send an list of id's to the server to update some information.  I do not want them to be a model class, theres no need for it.  What I am trying to do is put them into a serializer to make sure they are "clean".  Here is my code:

View Class:

```
class Update_Cards(APIView):
    # This seems necessary or it will throw an error
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    def post(self, request, board_id, format=None):
        print request.DATA
        serializer = CardMoveSerializer(data=request.DATA, many=True)
        #this throws an error
        print serializer.data

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializer:

```
class CardMoveSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    card_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    lane_id = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Error I get:

```
[{u'lane_id': 21, u'card_id': 3}] #this is to show the data is coming across the wire
Internal Server Error: /api/board/2/updateCards
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 327, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 324, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crob/Documents/workspace/tlckanban/python/rest/views.py", line 37, in post
    print card_moves.data
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 499, in data
    self._data = [self.to_native(item) for item in obj]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What I have done is implemented this with a simplejson parser for now, but I feel like its not the best way to do it:

```
def update_cards(request, board_id):
    json_data = simplejson.loads(request.body)

    for moveIndex in range(0, len(json_data)):
        #do some work


    return JSONResponse(json_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: what data are passing to the view? Can you include some sample?

Comment: It looks like you have a None value being passed in which the application does not like.

Comment: the very first line of the error message is printing request.DATA to the console.  I am sending: [{u'lane_id': 21, u'card_id': 3}] those are the only 2 properties so nothing should be None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be accessing 'serializer.is_valid()' before accessing the data. Looks like there's a missing bit of API there - serializer.data should probably raise an expection if its accessed before validation.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I didn't get the impression from the docs that I need to call is_valid, I thought just creating the instance would have made it available.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not using [Django's serializers](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/core/serializers) but anyway serialization is not made for validation. Use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) to validate your data then use `json` as you do to serialize it. Django's serializers are for querysets and models only.

Comment: I am using the django-rest-framework serializer:  basing my code off of this:  http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses.html

Comment: Yes, "serialization" as a concept is not used for "validation" but its part of Django's serializer module already. Look at the API guide for serializers, it exactly lets you serialize json to any object and not just models:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

ModelSerializer extends Serializer to support serializing json to models.